# mysql query not working no error ot anything

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
      $result53543534 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET credit=credit+1 WHERE email= '{$battle_get['username']}'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

But does not update. checked `$battle_get['username']` and the username is in there. 
i am not getting any errors or anything just not adding...

Any help would be very nice thanks in advance

Comment: You are using a username in the email field? Chances are the SQL is not finding a row with that `email` address.

Comment: email is supposed to be username, right? did you check it actually matches something?

Comment: Does PHP require a semicolon at the end of the statement - `UPDATE blah de blah WHERE email = 'thedata';`

Comment: have you tried logging/printing out one of the SQL's generated and running that in mysql client to see if your $battle_get... doesn't include extra spaces etc?

Comment: `$result53543534`? Dude.  Talk about "code smell".

Comment: @nick does the field email actually contains, EXACTLY, the username 'Nick12' ?

Comment: yes it is "nick12"  which is the same in the db

Comment: @nick why calling it 'email' when, actually, it contains usernames? also, check capitalization

Comment: tried hardcoding the username? `UPDATE users SET credit=credit+1 WHERE email= 'nick12'`

Comment: UPDATE users SET credit=credit+1 WHERE email= 'nick12' did not update it ether. Just so you no the credit collum is int(11)  in the db

Comment: I do the update by hand in phpmyadmin with  UPDATE `codedaddfly`.`users` SET `credit` = '1' WHERE `users`.`email` = 'nick12' AND `users`.`password` = 'gfdgdfgdf' AND `users`.`credit` =2 LIMIT 1 ;and works but how do i edit that ? so the were is only on email ?

Comment: How about checking the MySQL user permission to see if you have the permission(s) to UPDATE. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html

Answer (score 4):

See what the result from [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) is:

```
if ( ! $result53543534 = mysql_query( "UPDATE users SET credit=credit+1 WHERE email= '{$battle_get['username']}'") ) {
    die( mysql_error() );
} else {
    echo "Number of rows affected: " . mysql_affected_rows() . "<br>";
}
```

I may not have the syntax completely right but I hope you get the idea. If the result is 0, you're not specifying the `WHERE` syntax so that it actually refers to any row(s).

If the result is greater than 0, then you're mistaken if you think it's not affecting any rows. It may not be affecting the rows you think it should, but that's another issue.

Also, `echo` your sql statement so you can actually see exactly what it's doing.

Comment: Also, take that echoed sql statement and run it either in the command-line client or PHPMyAdmin to get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: I think I've fixed the syntax errors, try it again. If not, you can always write your own code calling `mysql_affected_rows()` :)

Comment: the page is not dieing and not showing any number or anything

Answer (score 0):

Try testing

```
$email = $battle_get['username'];
UPDATE users SET credit=credit+1 WHERE email= '$email'
```

Comment: I do the update by hand in phpmyadmin with  UPDATE `codedaddfly`.`users` SET `credit` = '1' WHERE `users`.`email` = 'nick12' AND `users`.`password` = 'gfdgdfgdf' AND `users`.`credit` =2 LIMIT 1 ;and works but how do i edit that ? so the were is only on email ?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot about committing the query to database, try transaction

```
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET credit=credit+1 WHERE email= '{$battle_get['username']}'");
mysql_query("COMMIT");
```

Comment: the databases connect is at the top of the page. I use  include_once('config.php'); on every page at the top  other sql scripts work with it so it is connecting ...

Comment: maybe your mysql settings set autocommit to 0, set it to 1

Comment: autocommit ? i am doind selects and inserts on my website on other pages... just update does not work

Comment: I do the update by hand in phpmyadmin with  UPDATE `codedaddfly`.`users` SET `credit` = '1' WHERE `users`.`email` = 'nick12' AND `users`.`password` = 'gfdgdfgdf' AND `users`.`credit` =2 LIMIT 1 ;and works but how do i edit that ? so the were is only on email ?

Comment: This is usually not needed in typical mysql installs.

Comment: have you try query in mysql query editor ? try UPDATE users SET credit=credit+1 WHERE LOWER(email) = LOWER('{$battle_get['username']}')

Comment: like i have said UPDATE codedaddfly.users SET credit = '1' WHERE users.email = 'nick12' AND users.password = 'gfdgdfgdf' AND users.credit =2 LIMIT 1 ;and works     works but i need to change that to just email

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing the code to as follows, it will allow you to examine the sql query. Try testing the sql query to see if it runs at all. You may also want to run DESCRIBE users on your mysql console to see what sort of information you get.

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET credit=credit+1 WHERE email= '{$battle_get['username']}'"
echo $sql;
if ( ! $result53543534 = mysql_query($sql) ) {
    die( mysql_error() );
} else {
    echo "Number of rows affected: " . mysql_affected_rows() . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Grant UPDATE permission to the user in the connection you're using for this. Just because the user is able to SELECT and INSERT, does not mean they can automatically UPDATE as well, you need to explicitly grant them the permission to UPDATE. And also mysql_error() will not show any error because your SQL statement is correct, hence no error shown.

Answer (score 0):

Happen to me the same thing, what I did first was to reproduce it on MySQL Workbench then use the SQL sentences from there, I found out (not sure why) it works adding parenthesis after the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE users SET credit = credit + 1 WHERE (`email`= '{$battle_get['username']}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check you mention name=email
And name=password attributes in all input field and also mention in name=submit in submit if it's input.